# Use JSpinner like JTable cell editor

Tags: java, swing, focus, tablecelleditor, jspinner

i'm using a JSpinner like a table cell editor, i have one annoying problem:

The cell remains in NON-editable mode until i click into it, for NON-editable i mean that i can't write into it(it has not focus so it doesn't accept inputs keyboard) but i can change the value with up-down arrows(of keyboard).

So, what i have to do to focus my table cell as soon as i press a key when it is selected?

Except for that problem my SpinnerEditor class works quite well.

Thanks all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, my solution now is this:

```
spinner.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        // editor is ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
        // necessary to set focus on the text component of jspinner
        editor.requestFocus();

        // this if you want to select the displayed text of jspinner
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run");
                editor.selectAll();
            }
        });
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but your solution doesn't work for me.  The focusGain method never get's called.  I copied your code exactly and created a field called "editor" and assigned it to the value you say to use.  What's the rest of your code look like for setting up the JTable and the CellEditor?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a complete example.  It does more than just put the JSpinner in the table, so you can read it and take what you need.  I found the answer by Blow to be incomplete and it didn't work for me, so here's something you can compile and run.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JSpinnerInTables {
    static String[] columnNames = {
        "Name","Value"
    };
    static Object[][] data = {
        {"one",1.0},
        {"two",2.0}
    };
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        //table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(1);
        tc.setCellEditor(new SpinnerEditor());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static class SpinnerEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    {
        JSpinner spinner;
        JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor;
        JTextField textField;
        boolean valueSet;

        // Initializes the spinner.
        public SpinnerEditor() {
            super(new JTextField());
            spinner = new JSpinner();
            editor = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor());
            textField = editor.getTextField();
            textField.addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
                public void focusGained( FocusEvent fe ) {
                    System.err.println("Got focus");
                    //textField.setSelectionStart(0);
                    //textField.setSelectionEnd(1);
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if ( valueSet ) {
                                textField.setCaretPosition(1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                public void focusLost( FocusEvent fe ) {
                }
            });
            textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
                    stopCellEditing();
                }
            });
        }

        // Prepares the spinner component and returns it.
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column
        ) {
            if ( !valueSet ) {
                spinner.setValue(value);
            }
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textField.requestFocus();
                }
            });
            return spinner;
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable( EventObject eo ) {
            System.err.println("isCellEditable");
            if ( eo instanceof KeyEvent ) {
                KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)eo;
                System.err.println("key event: "+ke.getKeyChar());
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
                //textField.select(1,1);
                //textField.setCaretPosition(1);
                //textField.moveCaretPosition(1);
                valueSet = true;
            } else {
                valueSet = false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Returns the spinners current value.
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return spinner.getValue();
        }

        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            System.err.println("Stopping edit");
            try {
                editor.commitEdit();
                spinner.commitEdit();
            } catch ( java.text.ParseException e ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Invalid value, discarding.");
            }
            return super.stopCellEditing();
        }
    }
}
```