# JTable add 2 mini button into a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I wanted to know how to add 2 small button into a cell. This is used for 'Quantity' column in my jtable.

[image]

I want to do as the image above, user are allowed to edit the number inside or clicking add or minus the number, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two arrows are part of a component called a `Spinner`. You can use a `JSpinner` to create textbox and use the `SpinnerNumberModel` to allow it to use numerical values:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel());
```

You can read more about spinners in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

To add it to a table, you will need a custom class which extends `DefaultCellEditor`. A few examples can be found here:

- [Is there a convenient way to use a spinner as an editor in a Swing JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882400/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-use-a-spinner-as-an-editor-in-a-swing-jtable)
- [Use JSpinner like JTable cell editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736993/use-jspinner-like-jtable-cell-editor)